# Computer's IP address used by another in closed network?

Tags: network, wifi, ip

I got an alert in the newest OSX (newest Macbook Air) and in Eduroam network that my IP address is used by another machine. 
This is my first time in life.

I think I may have been attacked because I was doing some important research at the time of interruption.

**What can be the reasons for such situation?**

I think it should be very rare situation.

**What does it mean that some other computer share the same IP address as yours in a closed network?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you mention is referred to as IP conflict. Most probable reason is misconfigured static settings on the other computer, nothing to worry about. Or it could be a DoS as in the router won't know where to forward the packets. In our eduroam infrastructure we automatically block these situations. Consult your University's NOC (Network Operations Centre, i.e. your network administrator.)

Answer (score 1):

As MemCtrl said it could be a misconfigured static settings on the other computer: In my old school there were 20 desktop with static IP addresses. If I assigned to my laptop one of those IP addresses, one desktop showed an alert message like yours. By the way you shouldn't worry about this. 
Try to consult the University's network administrator.